# DomDocument->saveXml without root node

Tags: php, simplexml, domdocument

Is it possible to get xml string form `DomDocument` or `SimpleXml` without root node? 
`DomDocument->saveXml()` returns this:

```
<root>
    <item>text</item>
    <item>text</item>
</root>
```

And I need:

```
<item>text</item>
<item>text</item>
```

Can I get this with `DomDocument`? Is there any way to do this without regexp?

Comment: That would not be a valid XML document, so having a method called `saveXML` return this would be kinda nonsense. So you will most likely have to use string manipulation, although not necessarily regex.

Comment: for what purpose do you need it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "inner XML" is like "inner HTML" of the `innerHTML` property, so used in Javascript and other languages...  I think we can ignore @michi comentary requiring some explanation. About @CBroe  commentary: not make sense if you imagine [DOMDocumentFragment](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php), or a string-XML replace from a innerXML to another (ex. filtered) XML. Your good example (of `item` list) is a string-XML that can be also converted to a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

---

The fasted and simplest way to get all XML is using the `saveXML()`, and it return a string that contains the string that you whant.

There are two ways to cut-off the part (a kind of "*trim* tag") that you not need:

### By DOM

A loop over all [$node->childNodes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes),  concatenating each subnode by `saveXML($subnode)`.

### By regex

Perhaps more simple and fast, but not secure, something like

```php
$innerXML = preg_replace(
    '#^\s*<([a-z0-9_:]+)[^>]*>(.+?)</\\1>\s*$#s', 
    '$2', 
    $dom->saveXML($node)
);
```